# "top" command shows %CPU as 1360, is it normal?

Tags: cpu, top-command

When I check processes with top command I see a process with 1360 as %CPU percentage. Is it normal? How should I interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

`top` reports the cpu usage as a %-age of a single cpu core. If your hardware has multiple cores and/or multiple cpus the total will be higher than 100%.

Example:

A server with 6 cpus that each has 4 cores will report 2400% at max load.